# Mysql "not in" select issue

Tags: mysql

I need to find in one table only , all persons having played to a contest today and not be winners from previous days...

My query is :

```
SELECT Email,FName,Name,ID 
FROM `voucher_registrations` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Date_Submitted`,'%Y-%c-%d') = curdate() 
and Email not in (select email 
                  from `voucher_registrations` 
                  where winner=1)
```

There is something wrong...mysql is not responding when I try to execute my query (**about 7000 rows in the table**)

Any idea ? Or another way to make this kind of query ?

Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

You can **add an index** on the email field to speed up the query and select "DISTINCT" email in subquery to reduce searched values:

```
SELECT Email,FName,Name,ID 
FROM `voucher_registrations` 
WHERE Date_Submitted = CURDATE()
  AND Email not in 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Email FROM`voucher_registrations` WHERE winner=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this (slightly different from yours):

```
SELECT Email,FName,Name,ID 
FROM `voucher_registrations` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Date_Submitted`,'%Y-%c-%d') = curdate() 
  AND Email NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT email FROM `voucher_registrations`
     WHERE winner = 1)
```

Comment: No. That would only filter winners on today's date. He wants to filter out winners from any date.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be the equivalent:

```
SELECT v.Email,v.FName,v.Name,v.ID 
FROM `voucher_registrations` v 
JOIN (select email from `voucher_registrations` where winner <>1)t on t.email=v.email
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`v.Date_Submitted`,'%Y-%c-%d') = curdate()
```

Comment: No. That would only filter winners on today's date. He wants to filter out winners from any date.

Comment: Gotcha, updated to use a join, doing an "in" is always faster then a "not in"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT vr1.Email,vr1.FName,vr1.Name,vr1.ID 
    FROM `voucher_registrations` vr1 
        LEFT JOIN `voucher_registrations` vr2
            ON vr1.Email = vr2.Email
                AND vr2.winner = 1
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(vr1.`Date_Submitted`,'%Y-%c-%d') = curdate() 
        AND vr2.Email IS NULL /* Email was not found among winners */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Email,FName,Name,ID 
FROM `voucher_registrations` 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`Date_Submitted`,'%Y-%c-%d') = curdate() 
and Email <> (select email 
              from `voucher_registrations` 
              where winner=1)
```